# child_process.fork - process.send does not return message

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, dom-events

I am running this script with node child_process.fork api.

That is my express application script, from where I start my application:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var express = require('express')
, routes = require('./routes')
, http = require('http')
, path = require('path');

var app = express();

//database connection
var connection  = require('express-myconnection'); 
var mysql = require('mysql');
//all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}


app.use(
        connection(mysql,{
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password : '',
            port : 3306, //port mysql
            database:'test-db'
        },'pool')
);

//routes
//app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/', routes.list);
app.use(app.router);

//run script
var cp = require('child_process');
var child = cp.fork('dataGrabber/pusherMysql');

child.on('message', function(m) {
    // Receive results from child process
    console.log('received: ' + m);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port') + ' http://localhost:' + app.get('port'));
});
```

That`s the part where I run my script:

```
//run script
var cp = require('child_process');
var child = cp.fork('dataGrabber/pusherAPI');

child.on('message', function(m) {
    // Receive results from child process
    console.log('received: ' + m);
});
```

As you can see I load my script and want to receive a message from the child.

That is my `pusherAPI.js` script:

```
var mysql  = require('mysql');
var Pusher = require('pusher-client');

/**
 * connect with mysql db
 */
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    database : 'test-db',
    port     : '3306',
    password : ''
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
        return;
    }

    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});

//connect with the server
var API_KEY = 'cb65d0a7a72cd94adf1f';
var pusher = new Pusher(API_KEY, {
    encrypted: true
}); 

var channel = pusher.subscribe("ticker.160");
channel.bind("message", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    this.data = data;

    /**
     * save data to db
     */
    var trade  = {
            timestamp           : data.trade.timestamp,
            price               : data.trade.topbuy.price, 
    };

    var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO trades SET ?', trade, function(err, result) {
        if (err) { 
            connection.rollback(function() {
                throw err;
            });
        }  

        //push message back to the app.js
        process.on('message', function(m) {
//          Pass results back to parent process
            m = "insert happened";
            process.send(m);
        });

        connection.commit(function(err) {
            if (err) { 
                connection.rollback(function() {
                    throw err;
                });
            }
        });
    });
    console.log(query.sql); 
});
```

I want to send a message back to my `app.js`, whenever an insertion happened to my `sql db`

My script starts and runs my queries. However, `process.send(m);` does not send anything back.

Any recommendations what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your answer!

**Update**

When changing my `pusherAPI.js` to, I get nothing back in the console.

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe("ticker.160");
process.on('insert_message', function(m) {
channel.bind("message", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        this.data = data;

        /**
         * save data to db
         */
        var trade  = {
                timestamp           : data.trade.timestamp,
                price               : data.trade.topbuy.price, 
        };

        var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO trades SET ?', trade, function(err, result) {
            if (err) { 
                connection.rollback(function() {
                    throw err;
                });
            }  

            //push message back to the app.js
    //          Pass results back to parent process
                m = "insert happened";
                process.send(m);


            connection.commit(function(err) {
                if (err) { 
                    connection.rollback(function() {
                        throw err;
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        console.log(query.sql); 
    });
});
```

In my `app.js` I changed my code like that:

```
//run script
var cp = require('child_process');
var child = cp.fork('dataGrabber/pusherAPI');

child.on('insert_message', function(m) {
    // Receive results from child process
    console.log('received: ' + m);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `process.send(m);` outside of the `message` event handler. Otherwise you're adding a new `message` event handler for every query and those event handlers only fire when the parent process sends it a message. Example:

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe("ticker.160");
channel.bind("message", function(data) {
    this.data = data;

    /**
     * save data to db
     */
    var trade  = {
      timestamp           : data.trade.timestamp,
      price               : data.trade.topbuy.price, 
    };
    var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO trades SET ?',
                                 trade,
                                 function(err, result) {
      if (err) { 
        connection.rollback(function() {
          throw err;
        });
        return;
      }  

      //push message back to the app.js
      m = "insert happened";
      process.send(m);

      connection.commit(function(err) {
        if (err) { 
          connection.rollback(function() {
            throw err;
          });
        }
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Where would you put `process.on('message', function(m) {
`?

Comment: If you need to accept messages from the parent process, add `process.on('message', ...)` outside of your `channel.bind("message", ...)` handler. That way only one `message` event handler gets added.

Comment: Thx for your answer! I tried your above proposed approach, but do not get anything back in my `app.js`. I would appreciate if you could take a look at my update.

Comment: don't wrap your `channel.bind("message", ...)` handler with `process.on('insert_message', function(m) {`. The latter isn't valid anyway. Also `child.on('message', ...)` for the parent process. Don't worry about adding `process.on('message', ...)` in the child process script until you have a need for the parent process to send a message to the child process.